# How to click on Yes No button on an alert (rather than Ok/Cancel) using selenium automation?

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, alert

I am trying to click on the **Yes/No** button on an alert popup message using **Selenium (java)**. I know we have accept() functions to click on the **Ok** buttons of any alert, but that doesn't work in this case.

I tried the below codes:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

This is the HTML code of the alert message:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
 <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
 <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner- 
 all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
  <span class="ui-button-text">Yes</span>
 </button>
 <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner- 
 all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
  <span class="ui-button-text">No</span>
 </button>
</div>
</div>
```

Please help!

Comment: Can you inspect pop up? If yes, share the HTML code.

Comment: Can you give us url?

Comment: I updated the question and shared the HTML code of the alert message.

Comment: Can you try with this (No need to switch to alert) : `new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Yes']/parent::button"))).click();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply **click** on **Yes** **button**. (No need to **switch to alert**) :

**Code :**

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Yes']/parent::button"))).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **parameterized** function to **Click** on **Yes/No**.
In case you want to click on Yes, use: `ClickYesNoButton("Yes");`
For No, call function as : `ClickYesNoButton("No");`

**Code below:**

```
public void ClickYesNoButton(String yesOrno){
                String myXpath =    "//span[text()='XXXX']";
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(myXpath.replace("XXXX", yesOrno))).click();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not `Javascript alert`.

Use this xpath to click that button

```
"//span[normalize-space()='Yes']/.."
```